Can a Heter Meah Rabannim be revoked?
A fellow is willing or wants to give a divorce to his wife, however his wife is unwilling or unable to accept.
The fellow may obtain a Heter Meah Rabannim, which includes 100 Rabbis from 3 different continents or countries giving him permission to deposit a divorce in Bais Din for his first wife, and thus allowing him to marry a second wife.
Once this person obtained the 100 signatories, can this be revoked by a signatory withdrawing their permission? Or once obtained it's good and done?

Hard to imagine it could be revoked after he already got remarried

I feel that way too. However news reports in recent days seem to indicate this may be something that can be done.

Related (on the subject of Heter Meah Rabannim): "Must a man seek 100 rabbis' permission again to take another "second" wife?"

Revoked because they realized they were not given the proper information when they signed (significant details withheld/obfuscated, or outright lied), or just because the rabbi had a change of heart? I think the former's a more interesting question. If you can show that the rabbis signed only based on outright lies...
